# How to get one record from one to many relationship table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, one is contact, one is company, the primary key for mapping is using Client code.

ContactTable

| Contact code | Client name | Client code | LoginName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MR YEO KWONG | 00005 | YEOW |
| 2 | MR DAVID Chan | 00005 | David |
| 3 | MS May Chen | 00005 | NULL |
| 4 | MS YORK | 200150 | MSYORK |

Company Table

| Company code | Company name | Contact Person | Client code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Co0001 | Company One | MR YEO KWONG | 00005 |
| Co0002 | David&Co. | MR DAVID Chan | 00005 |
| Co0003 | TESTING MAC LTD. | MS May Chen | 00005 |
| Co0004 | YORK Ltd. | MS YORK | 200150 |

I would like to have the result as below,

The Result I want is as below:

| Client code | Company name | Contact Person | Have Login |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00005 | Company One | MR YEO KWONG | MR YEO KWONG |
| 00005 | David&Co. | MR DAVID Chan | NULL |
| 00005 | TESTING MAC LTD. | MS May Chen | NULL |
| 200150 | YORK Ltd. | MS YORK | MS YORK |

I tried the left join & inner join, but in the last column, I don't know how to get one record that has the login name to show only.

---- New add

Client Table

| Client code | Client name | Company Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00005 | Client 1 | Co0001 |
| 00005 | Client 1 | Co0002 |
| 00005 | Client 1 | Co0003 |
| Co0004 | Client 2 | Co0004 |

Comment: You don't have a one to many relationship there, you have a many to many. Contacts 1, 2 and 3 are all related to Company Codes Co0001, Co0002, and Co0003.

Comment: would you explain how last column(Have Login) get values?

Comment: @Hamed_gibago (Have Login) column comes from Contact Table's LoginName. If contact have login name, will show the login name, if not show empty(null)

Comment: @Larnu but one company only has one contact person, but one contact can be more than one company's contact. 

PS. I added one more table - the client table

Comment: @KelsieChan I think your architecture design of tables are wrong. Why in rows 2 and 3 table result, column Have Login is null? I think it should be MR DAVID Chan and  MS May Chen

Comment: So you are `JOIN`ing on the client code *and* the name? Maybe a `CASE` expression and `ROW_NUMBER`? Showing us your attempts would really help here.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago NULL is correct, because i want to show one contact which have account only~~

Comment: Would you add table relations here?